# Trying to create custom data type in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I am trying to make custom datatype in typescript names as **email** so we can use **email**
as datatype so we can validate. and i came up with this code.

```
type Email = string & { __email: void } & RegExp;
const emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;

let a:Email = 'sdf@gmail.com';
```

But I don't know what i do wrong this not working and showing me error.

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Email'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ __email: void; }'.ts(2322)
```

So how i can solve this?

Comment: What you wrote is wishful thinking. There is a way to parse an email at compile time with a recursive type, but it won't be a type definition which you can annotate a value with, and there is a way to create a branded primitive type with an intersection as you did with `Email`, but you will have to assert that type.

Comment: Your email is a string, it does not make sense to have a type email

Comment: TS doesn't support regular expression validated string types; the relevant open feature request is at [ms/TS#41160](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160); anything else you do would be a workaround.  Will you know these email addresses at compile time?  (That is, are they sitting in string literals in your typescript code?)  Or will they only be known at runtime?